# ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() doesn't return the correct url. Returns /dev instead of /exec

Tags: url, redirect, google-apps-script, web-applications, publish

I have started to get a weird bug with Google Apps Script. ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() doesn't return the current url, but I am confident that a month ago when I created the project it worked perfectly.

In a page served by GAP, I have a header like so:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper teal lighten-1">
      <a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>?vue=search" class="brand-logo center">Project Database</a>
      <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li class="active"><a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>?vue=search">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() ?>?vue=create">Add Entry</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

When I go to the app through the link https://script.google.com/a/GSUITENAME/macros/s/ID/exec it works but when I click on the links in the header I get redirected like so https://script.google.com/macros/u/2/s/ID/dev?vue=create

So first of all I get redirected to a dev url and the "/a/GSUITENAME/" is lost. Since this URL is wrong i get a "Page not found" error

I hope someone can give me some pointers on what is going on, because according to the documentation I should get the proper url: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getService()
[image]

**EDIT:** When I test the project with the dev link it works as intended.

**EDIT2:** I did as [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) suggested and logout of all other google accounts except the one for that project. This time I get a functional url https://script.google.com/macros/s/ID/dev?vue=create but I still go from exec to dev which is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Are you testing the dev or published version?

Comment: I am testing the published version, I am going for the link that has the exec at the end

Comment: When i test the dev version the links work as intended

Comment: *I get redirected* Logout of all other accounts except `GSUITENAME`

Comment: When I logout of my other accounts it removes the /u/2 of the url but it still goes from exec to dev

Comment: Seems no better way than to hardcode the url